# Mutual TLS Authentication : validate client cert

Tags: certificate, client-certificates

I am not sure if we simply validating the client cert is enough, because if someone steal the cert then they can impersonate others, how do we validating the client? Does client needs to sign some message with its private key , send together with the client cert, and server side get the public key from the cert to validate the message to confirm he is the cert holder?

Answer (score 0):

When a server validates a client certificate, it makes the client prove that the certificate is theirs by performing an operation with its corresponding private key. The private key isn't part of the certificate, so stealing it doesn't allow impersonation of the user.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how the operation happen with the private key? Does it mean client need to supply the private key in the request or client need to sign something in the request?

Comment: The client never, ever supplies the private key to the server. It will only ever decrypt or sign things with it.

Comment: Can you explain how “by performing an operation with its corresponding private key”? Thanks